# composer require --dev laravel/dusk:^1.0 give Nothing to install or update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

trying to install laravel/dusk 
give me this error

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
 PHP Warning:  Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
 The compiled services file has been removed.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
```

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the information it seems you have already installed Laravel Dusk. Go to `vendor/laravel` directory and verify whether you have `dusk` folder inside.

Obviously to complete installation you should follow [Dusk installation guide.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#installation)